# T-distribution, to use or to not use

Tags: statistics, probability, sampling

The question is asking to find if probability of having average low or low as 18?

I have mu = 20, n = 25, X bar = 18, and std dev = 2

Since I do not have variance, I assume I am supposed to use t-distribution over z and chi distribution however when I use the formula t = (X bar - mu)/(std dev)/sqrt(n) i get -5 (P>5) which is not on the t-table?

What am I doing wrong

Comment: Well, to assess the calculated result intuitively, the way to think about it is that the mean of a sample of size 25 should have a standard deviation of about (std dev)/sqrt(25) = 2/5, and the observed difference, 18 - 20 = -2, is much larger than that. So on the face of it, it seems like the observed difference should be surprising, i.e. that it has a low p-value. I don't see anything incorrect here, although I could be wrong. Btw questions such as this are off topic on SO; try stats.stackexchange.com instead.